# How can I Query DocumentDB with a Hydrating subquery?

Tags: .net, linq, azure-cosmosdb, nosql

if I have 2 documents in my DocumentDB collection

'Document A'

```
{ "id": 123, "OtherDocId": 456, "Bdoc" : null }
```

and 'Document B'

```
{ "id": 456, "name": "" }
```

how can I I get Document A so that it looks like this

```
{ "id": 123, "OtherDocId": 456, "Bdoc" : { "id": 456, "name": "" }}
```

If it was SQL I could do somthing like

```
SELECT *, some-sub-query-here AS 'BDOC' from...
```

I'm not trying to turn a no-sql into a relational DB but I have a regularly updated document (Bdoc) that is associated with some of the documents in the collection and I don't want to have to do 2 round trips to get a document find it's Bdocid and then fetch it's associated Bdoc then put them together in some for loop.

If I do it straight nosql style then the Bdoc is copied in each of the A documents and Bdoc becomes a maintenance mess every time I want to update it since I have to update every document that Bdocid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't combine two separate documents using the SQL grammar (that effectively is a relational or cross-document join).

If you're looking to avoid 2 network round-trips, you could write a stored procedure that does two separate lookup and transformation.